# Load more repeating same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to load more comments when click on loadmore div. When I click Loadmore, this code is rendering the same values which I've rendered initially.For example if I rendered 10 comments initially, when I click on load more it was rendering the same 10 comments.

In index.html.erb

```
<div class="main-content"><%= render :partial => 'comment' %></div>
<div class="loadmore" onclick="send()">Loadmore</div>
```

In _comment.html.erb

```
 <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
 <%= comment.comments %>
 <%= end %>
```

In my controller

```
@comments = Comment.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]).all(:order => 'updated_at DESC')
respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comments }
end
```

In javascript

```
function send(){

     $.ajax({
        url: '<%= escape_javascript comments_path(:page =>(@comments.current_page)+1) %>',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',           
        success: function(){                     
                 $(".main-content").append("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'comment' %>");
            }       
    });
}
```

If the code is wrong, suggest me the right code.

Comment: I suppose @comments.current_page executes when you click on button, so it check page params and it its still same, its empty. Try to update data-page attribute in your div#loadmore attribute each time you click on button

Comment: But my page param is passing as 2, also my query formation in my log is correct, but it's appending same values

Comment: Can you show actual params sent to server and SQL query that executes, when you click button?

Comment: parameters `{"page"=>"2", "amp"=>nil}`, and query `SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

Comment: and the next time you click it, what parameters and sql requests are?

Comment: same parameters and same query.

Comment: so are you sure that you update page params as you say?

Comment: Only at first time, and then for every click I'm getting same parameters and same query, but rendering first 10 values consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

your `params[:page]` is not updated every time you hit the button, you need to reset your `params[:page]` with adding the `offset` value to it everytime before you pass it

Comment: params[:page] is resetting since my query formation in my log is correct

Comment: if this is your query I think it should work fine `SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`. could you check for the query everytime you hit for loadmore and see for value of `offset` set in query..

Comment: I'm getting same parameters and same query for every click, and rendering same values.

Comment: there is your problem, your offset needs to be changed on every query hit, see from where your offset variable is set and on each hit update the value for offset, something like this : `offset+=10`

Comment: at first time offset is updated, but it rendered same first 10 values,  if it needs to be update, how and where can I do this?

Comment: in your `ajax call` pass it as a parameter, handle that parameter in your controller and pass it as an offset while triggering your query

Comment: getting same response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can try this in your view:

```
<div class="main-content"><%= render :partial => 'comment' %></div>
<div class="loadmore" onclick="send()" id="loadmore_button" data-page="2">Loadmore</div>
```

after that in javascript you need to get current page, and update old value to be with new page-data

```
function send(){
 var pager = $("#loadmore_button").data("page")
 $.ajax({
    url: '<%= escape_javascript comments_path %>?page='+pager,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',           
    success: function(){                     
      $(".main-content").append("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'comment' %>");
      $("#loadmore_button").data("page", parseInt(pager)+1)
    }       
  });
}
```

Comment: No improvements, getting same again.

Comment: please give params and SQL at server side

Comment: `Parameters: {"page"=>"2"}`, `SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`